# Invariance of phase portrait with respect to rotations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My task is to draw a phase portrait for a planar system of differential equations: $\dot x = 2 xy$, $\dot y = x^2 - y^2$. I have already managed to compute the stationary points and observed that there are easy to find trajectories contained in three lines: $x = 0$ and  $y = \pm x / {\sqrt 3}$. What else can I do?

With an aid of computer algebra systems I am aware of the part of my portrait between $y = x / \sqrt 3$ and $y = - x / \sqrt 3$. If somebody could help me how to show the invariance of my system with respect to rotation around the zero by $\frac 2 3 \pi$, I would be done.

I'm afraid that there is no closed form solution to this, that's why I have encountered such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closed form solution, but in the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ defined by $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, is $$(r(t))^3\cos(3\theta(t))=c,$$ which proves the asymptotes when $\cos(3\theta)\to0$, that is, at every $\theta$ in $\pi/6+\pi\mathbb Z/3$.

As a confirmation, a plot of the solutions, showing the antisymmetry by $\pi/3$ rotations and the symmetry by $2\pi/3$ rotations:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Act the rotation transformation $T(u,v)=(-\frac{1}{2}u+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}v,-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}u-\frac{1}{2}v)$ on your solutions $\phi(t):=(x(t),y(t))$.  Then show that the curve $$T\circ \phi(t)=(-\frac{1}{2}x(t)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y(t),-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x(t)-\frac{1}{2}y(t))$$ satisfies the differential equations.